# Javascript - sum 2d arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 2d arrays

```
var arr1 = [
  [1, 'a'],
  [2, 'b']
]

var arr2 = [
  [3, 'a'],
  [5, 'c']
]
```

I would like to sum these 2 arrays to get this result

```
var output = [
  [4, 'a'],
  [2, 'b'],
  [5, 'c']
]
```

I tried writing 2 `.map` functions but along with the desired results this will return a lot of duplicates:

```
function sumArrays (arr1, arr2) {
  var output = [];
  arr2.map(function(i) {
    arr1.map(function(n) {
      if (i[1] === n[1]) {
        output.push([i[0] + n[0], i[1]])
      } else {
        output.push(i)
      }
    })
  })
  return output;
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this, or should I now be removing everything but the highest value for a specific string?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you like to get a new array with the combined result?

Comment: I need to return the sum of both arrays. I can either do this by modifying the existing ones, or returning a new one.

Comment: Would be easier with a map, as in `{a : 4, b : 2, c : 5}`

Comment: `arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((a,b)=>{return b[1] in a?a[b[1]]+=b[0]:a[b[1]]=b[0],a;},{});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use not [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), when you do not need a new array, which this method returns.

You could use a hash table for the inventory and check against and update `arr2` with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Proposal which uses `arr1` for update

```js
var arr1 = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']],
    arr2 = [[3, 'a'], [5, 'c']],
    inventory = Object.create(null);

arr1.forEach(function (a) {
    this[a[1]] = a;
}, inventory);

arr2.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a[1]]) {
        this[a[1]] = [0, a[1]];
        arr1.push(this[a[1]]);
    }
    this[a[1]][0] += a[0];
}, inventory);

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Proposal with new array for `result`.

```js
var arr1 = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']],
    arr2 = [[3, 'a'], [5, 'c']],
    inventory = Object.create(null),
    result = arr1.map(function (a) {
        return this[a[1]] = [a[0], a[1]];
    }, inventory);

arr2.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a[1]]) {
        this[a[1]] = [0, a[1]];
        result.push(this[a[1]]);
    }
    this[a[1]][0] += a[0];
}, inventory);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice trick with the console

Comment: Good explanation. But, the expected result is an array, so why don't use an array?

Comment: @PraneshRavi, the result is an array, where don't you see an array?

Comment: Typo! Why don't you use map()?

Comment: you mean `Map`? ES6?

Answer (score 0):

This question is essentially the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40184870/5459839), where I suggested the same ES6 code, using hashes (Set) and some variant code which I will not repeat here:

```js
function sumArrays(a, b) {
    return Array.from(
        b.reduce( (m, [v,k]) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + v),
                   new Map(a.map ( ([v,k]) => [k,v] )) ), // swap pairs
        ([k,v]) => [v,k]) // swap back afterwards;
}

var arr1 = [
  [1, 'a'],
  [2, 'b']
]

var arr2 = [
  [3, 'a'],
  [5, 'c']
]

var result = sumArrays(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with `forEach()` and `findIndex()`.

```js
var arr1 = [
  [1, 'a'],
  [2, 'b']
]

var arr2 = [
  [3, 'a'],
  [5, 'c']
]

function sumArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  var r = arr1.slice(0);
  arr2.forEach(function(e) {
    var i = arr1.findIndex(function(a) {
      return e[1] == a[1];
    })
    i != -1 ? r[i][0] += e[0] : r.push(e)
  })
  return r;
}

console.log(sumArrays(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat both arrays, such that you have one array with all the tuples.

Then *reduce* that array of tuples, such that any compatible tuples get accumulated.

```js
arr1.concat(arr2).reduce(function r(accumulator, iterand) {

    // base case: no tuples in accumulator
    if (accumulator.length == 0) {
        // add current tuple to our empty accumulator.
        return [iterand];
    }

    // first tuple in accumulator is compatible with the currently-inspected tuple
    if (accumulator[0][1] == iterand[1]) {
        // increment the count in the compatible tuple that already exists in the accumulator
        return [[accumulator[0][0]+iterand[0], accumulator[0][1]]].concat(accumulator.slice(1));
    }

    // currently-inspected tuple is not compatible with first tuple in accumulator. leave first tuple in accumulator unchanged. run the inductive case upon the remaining tuples in the accumulator.
    return [accumulator[0]].concat(r(accumulator.slice(1), iterand));

}, [])
```

This is a functional solution which will not mutate any of your existing input data.